# Packages interfering with other packages on R?

Tags: r, restrictions

I am working on a long R studio script for an experiment (more than 3000 lines) with different kinds of analyses that are not too complicated but combined there a lot of different kinds of analyses there. I come across problems where I have loaded one package from the library (e.g. "MASS") and then I can no longer do a function from another package, e.g. select() because it produces an error message when I use it. My way around it so far has been to restart R and to be really careful with the order of the packages that have loaded; so that I have done all of the necessary parts with e.g. select() before I load e.g. "MASS". I am reluctant to start a new script for every analysis that I do, because it seems like it is so much easier to work with one script and e.g. pinch bits of code from other analyses. Is there a better solution to resolve this?

Comment: This is exactly the problem the operators `::` and `:::` were created to solve.  You have a more fundamental problem, though: no script of 3000 lines can be adequately tested and verified.  Restructuring it (using principles of encapsulation, modularization, and unit testing) will help you assure its correctness--to the extent that can be done--by allowing you to test a collection of smaller simpler components.  In the process you can create isolated namespaces (`R` "environments") to protect against object name collisions.

Comment: Hey thanks, sure I would never run the script all at once- it is more like a document with many different analyses and then I run a subset of the analysis that I want to do for a specific statistical test or visual representation. The actual analyses are checked separately. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah MASS affects and masks functions from dplyr and plyr. As annoying as it is, one way I've gotten around it is doing dplyr::select(). Alternatively you can add and remove MASS where you need it, which is also annoying. Sorry! Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answering! Gosh I am glad that there is a quicker way for dealing with it than restarting the program. Annoying! Thanks for explaining! :)